# Codeigniter, Paypal api by Angelleye - Send payment to Single receiver

Tags: codeigniter, paypal, paypal-adaptive-payments

I am trying to send money from admin(site super admin) using paypal merchant account to one of the users using their email address(getting their paypal verified status beforehand). But it is throwing error with *Code: 520002* and *Message: Internal Error*. I don't know whats wrong. Can anyone please help me solve this problem?

I am using Pay function of Paypal library for Codeigniter by Angelleye https://github.com/angelleye/paypal-codeigniter.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve my problem. I was loading library in function. I moved it to constructor of controller and it started working.